# Map reduce implementation per text file

Tags: text, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, createfile

I need to count term frequency of each word per document so i want to implement map reduce functions per text file.**how to implement map() and reduce() per text file?**

And another problem in Map-Reduce is
  Map-Reduce writes output from reduce to single file /user/output/part-0000 and **project need to write each file processed output in different text files, how to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mentioned below:

1. In job file compute number of input files
2. Set `numreducers` equal to number of input files
3. Assign numbers 0 to n-1 to files and pass this information to distributed cache
4. Get file name in `setup()` method of mapper and retrieve assigned number for that file and assign it to some static variable
5. From `Partitioner` return this static variable

Reducer will emit 'n' files.